# ruby, selenium, how to click hrefs in an array

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have constructed an array of hrefs, when I do puts names_href I got

```
["https://demo.massbrc.com/applicants/57/applicant_identity_documents/new", "https://demo.massbrc.com/applicants/47/applicant_identity_documents/new"]
```

I want to iterarte this array and click it's elements :

```
names_href.each { |x| x.click }
```

I got this error :

private method `click' called for #<String:0x000000000543f800> (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb:131:in`block (2 levels) in '

Thanks,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: HI, Made a small mistake, I have updated my code once again, Can you check and let me know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Beacause the array element (string) doesn't have click method.

For example, you must create the `<a>` and set the `href` attribute with element array ("href")

```
<% names_href.each do |x| %>
  <a href="#{x}"> your_text </a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: "For example". With the "x" element you can do what you need. Ruby code: '<% link_to "title", x %>

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the links are on the same page, so once after clicking on the link, it would navigate to another page, so to click the subsequent links, I am bringing the back the page by clicking the back button

```
arr=["https://demo.massbrc.com/applicants/57/applicant_identity_documents/new", "https://demo.massbrc.com/applicants/47/applicant_identity_documents/new"]


arr.each do |link|
  driver.find_element(xpath: "//*[@href='#{link}']").click
  driver.navigate.back
end
```

Comment: thank you, but I got this : Given xpath expression "//*[@href=https://prgdemo.massbrc.com/applicants/57/applicant_identity_documents/new]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)

Comment: Unable to locate element: //*[@href='https://prgdemo.massbrc.com/applicants/57/applicant_identity_documents/new']

Comment: sorry, I can't we are using vpn to connect, it's a sensitive data.

Comment: I created a small ruby example, it's not working too :    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome
driver.get "http://www.google.com"
arr=["http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.rcn.com"]


arr.each do |link|
  driver.find_element(:xpath,"//*[@href='#{link}']").click
  driver.navigate.back
end

Comment: @Fatna Hey wait, You are going to the google.com and then you are clicking the yahoo.com? what?  Yahoo.com link is appearing in Google.com page?

Comment: @Fatna I think you are missing the very basics of automation inthisplace, I thought links are present in the site you have given, but your recently given examples tells me that's not the case, the above code of mine would click the element which has the attribute href with the given value.

Comment: I was just trying ti simulate the process, in our case, the user login, click a link, the filter slide from right of screen, enter from and to birth date, click ok, some rows show, but in all the columns that show we can't see the birth date, to see the birth date you have to click on the name , it will take you to another page, what I did I collected all the Name column get the link of each name, and tried to do click one by one.

Comment: @Fatna The above example of yours says to me that you are lacking the very basics of automation, you are opening the google page and then you are trying to click yahoo.com and rcn.com link, this says to me that you haven't understood the way automation works, when you call driver.find_element it would find that element for you! By the way I am leaving you here because I can't help you without the webpage.

Comment: please forget about the google example, perhaps I does not reflect what we have, thank you anyway, you helped me lot,

Comment: @Fatna When you try to click something, webpage has to consist of that element, otherwise it wouldn't find that element, that's why `unable to locate element ` was thrown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169353/discussion-between-fatna-and-rajagopalan).